# optimize the model after modeling in r randomforste grid search

Tags: r, optimization, heuristics

there i have two regression models ,rf1 and rf2 and i want o find value of variables that allow output of rf1 to be between 20 and 26 and output of rf2 should be inferior to 10 :[image]

i tried grid search but i found nothing,please i you know how to do it with a heuristic (simulated annealing or genetic algorithm) please help me

you can find the code for this example in this repository  [here](https://github.com/oujbih/stackoverflow.git)

```
library(randomForest)

model_rf_fines<- readRDS(file = paste0("rf1.rds"))
model_rf_gros<- readRDS(file = paste0("rf2.rds"))
#grid------
grid_input_test = expand.grid(
  "Poste" ="P1",
  "Qualité" ="BTNBA",
  "CPT_2500" =13.83,
  "CPT400" = 46.04,
  "CPT160" =15.12,
  "CPT125" =5.9,
  "CPT40"=15.09,
  "CPT_40"=4.02,
  "retart"=0,
  "dure"=0,
  'Débit_CV004'=seq(1300,1400,10),
  "Dilution_SB002"=seq(334.68,400,10),
  "Arrosage_Crible_SC003"=seq(250,300,10),
  "Dilution_HP14"=1200,
  "Dilution_HP15"=631.1,
  "Dilution_HP18"=500,
  "Dilution_HP19"=seq(760.47,800,10),
  "Pression_PK12"=c(0.59,0.4),
  "Pression_PK13"=c(0.8,0.7),
  "Pression_PK14"=c(0.8,0.9,0.99,1),
  "Pression_PK16"=c(0.5),
  "Pression_PK18"=c(0.4,0.5)
  
)

#levels correction ----
levels(grid_input_test$Qualité) = model_rf_fines$forest$xlevels$Qualité
levels(grid_input_test$Poste) = model_rf_fines$forest$xlevels$Poste

for(i in 1:nrow(grid_input_test)){
  #fines
  print("----------------------------")
  print(i)
  print(paste0('Fines       :', predict(object = model_rf_fines,newdata = grid_input_test[i,]) ))
  #gros
  print(paste0('Gros        :',predict(object = model_rf_gros,newdata = grid_input_test[i,]) ))
  if(predict(object = model_rf_gros,newdata = grid_input_test[i,])<=10){break}
}
```

any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be such variables/input does not exists. If `rf1` and `rf2` represent two Random Forest models, with say >50 trees, the number of trees will average out spikes/edges of the model.

Similar to the law of large numbers, the more trees in each forest, the more closer output of `rf1` and `rf2` will be. This is all if indeed `rf_` represent random forests both trained on same data, indeed than the more trees the more impossible your input that satisfies the conditions.

Indeed try a naive grid search first, and keep track of minimum value of `rf2` while `rf1` satisfies your condition. Call this minimum `M_grid`

If you want to implement simulated annealing, I would start with a simple neighbour scheme, say take a random input variable and vary it a bit. Use python packages for the annealing scheme. If this simple scheme beats your `M_grid` by quite a bit and you feel you are close to the solution, you can play around with slower cooling schemes, or more complicated neighbour proposals.

Also, the objective for both SA and GA should not be chosen too fast. Probably you want a objective that steers `rf1` close to its lowest edge of 20, and `rf2`   as minium as possible, with maybe a `exp()` or `**3` to reward going down plenty.

I made some assumptions here, maybe wrong. But hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion @user3184950